# How do i add % and per minute function with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i need help from someone that understands my problem, i am trying to add 10% after the total estimate and also per minute 0.35 a minute how can i add this in this script i tried var results: pct / 10; did not do it, can someone in the name of God help me out to fix this problem i would really appreciate this.

```html
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
//--------------Settings-------------------------------- 
//ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code, use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO 3166-2_alpha-2#US
var countrycode="US"
//Rate per mil (2.00)
var ratepermi=2.50;
//Minimum fare (60)
var minimum_fare=50;
//Currrency Symbol
var currencysymbol="$";
//Avoid motorways / highways? true/false
var avoidHighways=false;
//Avoid toll roads? true/false
var avoidTolls=false;
//Show summary? true/false
var showsummary=false;
//Disclaimer text
var disclaimer="Please be aware this is only an estimated fare and the final price will be quoted on request"
//----------End Settings-------------------------------- 
 
function initialize() 
{
 var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: countrycode}};
 var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('inputfrom'));
 var searchBoxfrom = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
 var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('inputto'));
 var searchBoxto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
}

function ftn_estimate()
{
 if (document.getElementById('inputfrom').value!="" && document.getElementById('inputto').value!="")
 {
  var origin = document.getElementById('inputfrom').value;
  var destination = document.getElementById('inputto').value;
  
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
   origins: [origin],
   destinations: [destination],
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
   unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
   avoidHighways: avoidHighways,
   avoidTolls: avoidTolls,
    }, callback); 
 }
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
   
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

  if(showsummary)
  {
   document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML=origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]  + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '+ results[j].duration.text;
   document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML+="<br /><font color='red'>" + disclaimer + "</font>"
  }
  document.getElementById('distance').value=(results[j].distance.value/1609.34).toFixed(1);
  document.getElementById('time').value=(results[j].duration.value/60).toFixed(1);
  
  var calc_fare=(results[j].distance.value/1609.34)*ratepermi;
  
  if (calc_fare<minimum_fare)
  {
   calc_fare=minimum_fare;
  } 
  document.getElementById('fare').value=currencysymbol+calc_fare.toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<link href="../../../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<center>
      <div id="formbox">
        <h1 class="fare_title">FARE ESTIMATE</h1>
               <div class="div1">
                 <span class="ride">Ride in Style</span><img class="check_icon" src="../../../../check2.png" alt="check1"><span class="ride">Safe and Reliable</span><img class="check_icon" src="../../../../check2.png" alt="check1"><span class="ride">Fully Licensed</span><img class="check_icon" src="../../../../check2.png" alt="check1"/>
               </div>
        <input id="inputfrom" type="text" placeholder="From" style="width:400px" class="inputform">
        <h3 style="margin-top: 10px; color: #3F3F3F; text-transform: uppercase;">to</h3>
        <input id="inputto" type="text" placeholder="To" style="width:400px" class="inputto">
        <br/>
        <input type="button" onclick="ftn_estimate();" value="Estimate Fare" class="fare_button">
        <br/><br/>
        <table class="resultsbox">
            <tr><td class="time_style">Time (mins)</td><td><input id="time" readonly type="text" placeholder="--"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="distance_style">Distance (mi)</td><td><input id="distance" readonly type="text" placeholder="--"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="fare_style">Estimated Fare</td><td><input id="fare" readonly type="text" placeholder="--"></td></tr>
        </table>
        
        <span id="summary"></span>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: It would be good if you only shared relevant parts of your code, and rephrased your question to be  clearer. If I understand correctly, you want to add 10% of a value to that value... `variable += 0.1 * variable`

Comment: Im sorry if i did not clarify my question. above where i added. var ratepermi=2.50;
var minimum_fare=50;. I want to add 10% charge after the total charge 2.50 per mile + 0.35 = total then i want to add that 10% to give the final results of the estimate. Hope i did not confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
//--------------Settings-------------------------------- 
//ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code, use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO 3166-2_alpha-2#US
var countrycode="US"
//Rate per mil (2.00)
var ratepermi=2.50;
//Minimum fare (60)
var minimum_fare=50;
//Currrency Symbol
var currencysymbol="$";
//Avoid motorways / highways? true/false
var avoidHighways=false;
//Avoid toll roads? true/false
var avoidTolls=false;
//Show summary? true/false
var showsummary=false;
//Disclaimer text
var disclaimer="Please be aware this is only an estimated fare and the final price will be quoted on request"

var rateperminute=0.35;
var ratio=1.1; // Price will be 110% of the computed estimate

//----------End Settings-------------------------------- 
 
function initialize() 
{
 var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: countrycode}};
 var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('inputfrom'));
 var searchBoxfrom = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
 var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('inputto'));
 var searchBoxto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
}

function ftn_estimate()
{
 if (document.getElementById('inputfrom').value!="" && document.getElementById('inputto').value!="")
 {
  var origin = document.getElementById('inputfrom').value;
  var destination = document.getElementById('inputto').value;
  
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
   origins: [origin],
   destinations: [destination],
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
   unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
   avoidHighways: avoidHighways,
   avoidTolls: avoidTolls,
    }, callback); 
 }
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
   
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

  if(showsummary)
  {
   document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML=origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]  + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '+ results[j].duration.text;
   document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML+="<br /><font color='red'>" + disclaimer + "</font>"
  }
  document.getElementById('distance').value=(results[j].distance.value/1609.34).toFixed(1);
  document.getElementById('time').value=(results[j].duration.value/60).toFixed(1);
  
  var calc_fare_dist=(results[j].distance.value/1609.34)*ratepermi;
  var calc_fare_time=(results[j].duration.value/60)*rateperminute;
  // Provided you want to add 0.35 per minute to the "per mile price"
  var calc_fare = (calc_fare_dist + calc_fare_time)*ratio;

  
  if (calc_fare<minimum_fare)
  {
   calc_fare=minimum_fare;
  } 
  document.getElementById('fare').value=currencysymbol+calc_fare.toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<link href="../../../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<center>
      <div id="formbox">
        <h1 class="fare_title">FARE ESTIMATE</h1>
               <div class="div1">
                 <span class="ride">Ride in Style</span><img class="check_icon" src="../../../../check2.png" alt="check1"><span class="ride">Safe and Reliable</span><img class="check_icon" src="../../../../check2.png" alt="check1"><span class="ride">Fully Licensed</span><img class="check_icon" src="../../../../check2.png" alt="check1"/>
               </div>
        <input id="inputfrom" type="text" placeholder="From" style="width:400px" class="inputform">
        <h3 style="margin-top: 10px; color: #3F3F3F; text-transform: uppercase;">to</h3>
        <input id="inputto" type="text" placeholder="To" style="width:400px" class="inputto">
        <br/>
        <input type="button" onclick="ftn_estimate();" value="Estimate Fare" class="fare_button">
        <br/><br/>
        <table class="resultsbox">
            <tr><td class="time_style">Time (mins)</td><td><input id="time" readonly type="text" placeholder="--"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="distance_style">Distance (mi)</td><td><input id="distance" readonly type="text" placeholder="--"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="fare_style">Estimated Fare</td><td><input id="fare" readonly type="text" placeholder="--"></td></tr>
        </table>
        
        <span id="summary"></span>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Thank You So So much that worked. So now i want to understand this part so i can lock it in my head. So why is var rateperminute=0.35 added after var showsummary=false;
//Disclaimer text
var disclaimer="Please be aware this is only an estimated fare and the final price will be quoted on request" does it make a difference if it was after the ratepermile or no? and how does this work var ratio=1.1; // Price will be 110% of the computed estimate if you do not mind explaining thank you.

Comment: another thing the TIME (MINS) it calculates total minutes from A to B where do i change this to Hours-Minutes.

Comment: The place where you define rateperminute has no importance (as long as you define it before using it).
About the "ratio = 1.1", if you want to add 10% to calc_fare, you actually want to have 100% calc_fare + 10% of calc_fare: you want 110% of calc_fare, so you can multiply calc_fare by 110/100 (= 1.1)